# Laravel 5.3 - Send welcome email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i'm new in laravel 5.3, i created system user using:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But now i would like send email after registration, in my AuthController i'm tryng like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $body = view('email/welcome');
    $mail = new Message;
    $mail->setFrom('mywebsite.it <info@mywebsite.it>')
    ->addTo($data['email'])
    ->setSubject('Welcome');
    $mail->setHTMLBody($body);
    $mailer = new SmtpMailer([
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'xxxxxx',
    'secure' => 'ssl',
    'port' => '465',
    ]);
    $mailer->send($mail);

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

}
```

it doesn't work, after register new user i don't receive the email. My code about send email work well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to send welcome email after registration , you need to generate Mailable Class and use the Mail facacade to send email to the user just after we insert the user details in our database.

Follow this article for detailed tutorial with Laravel 5.5

https://www.5balloons.info/send-email-on-registration-with-laravel-5-5-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Create `UserRegistered()` [mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#generating-mailables) and the send it using this code:

```
....

$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
]);

Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new UserRegistered());

return $user;
```

If you're using Laravel 5.3, you may want to [use notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications).